# Fresh Ubuntu 18.04 Overheating and Battery Problem

Tags: battery, overheating

I bought a new laptop : HP Pavilion 15 CB001NT.

Specifications :

i7 7700hq - 16 gb ram - gtx 1050 - 1 tb hdd & 256 gb ssd

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 along side Windows 10 (SSD). Also I installed latest nvidia driver (`nvidia-396`). But the machine is too hot and battery drains fastly. I looked `htop`, CPU and Memory are working fine.
The machine is new and ubuntu is fresh installed.

So where is the problem? What should I do?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Laptop overheating can be many things.  If it is not high CPU usage then one possibility is that air circulation is not good.  If you use the laptop on a soft surface the airflow can be blocked.  I use a laptop cooler fan (which also is a kind of stand) but you could use something as simple as a tray or really anything that gives some room for air underneath.  The added fan usage might be what is causing your battery to drain faster.